# Creating subfolders in the media library

Tags: media, media-library, directory, customization

I'm new to WordPress. As far as I can tell, there's no built-in way to manually organize uploaded media into subfolders. There are free plugins that enable categorization, but this does not affect a file's path.

Is there some free plugin that allows for actual sorting into folders? Can someone involved in WordPress development say if this a feature that will be implemented natively in a future release?

Comment: Closest thing I'm aware of is to use Custom Upload Dir - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/ - and to check whether it's something that will be worked on you could check out the Make blog - https://make.wordpress.org/core/